# Finding simple worked exercises for Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

I am in the process of learning Category Theory with the purpose of being able to create a game that will help explain it to others in a simple way. I have read many texts and articles about it. While I have learnt some of the definitions, I have found it hard to be able to create concrete examples of a lot of the concepts and especially depict them in a visual way (things such as Natural Transformations, Functors, Cartesian Closed Categories etc.)

I am a computer science undergraduate with only a simple mathematical background, and due to this I find much of the reading material on category theory too difficult to follow (I also don't have a background in functional programming). I am looking for some simple worked examples that I can go through and understand, and then hopefully translate into a visual representation to help explain to others.

If any of you could help me by creating or locating such a resource I would be very appreciative!

EDIT: Thank you for both responses

Comment: I like Awodey's text http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0199237182/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1449094924&sr=8-1&pi=AC_SX110_SY165_QL70&keywords=awodey. You can also find introductions on youtube: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=P6DvIfTJhx8 and https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=If6VUXZIB-4. For constructing examples, I always try to think about what new concepts mean in Posets (as categories), Monoids (as categories), Sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of examples and exercises in "Category Theory for the Sciences" by David I. Spivak. The book is intended for non-mathematicians. There is free online version at http://category-theory.mitpress.mit.edu/